# Some odd residents

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

My friend went on vacation recently, and told me that the place he visited had some interesting denizens. Here's what he had to say about them:

> Some are high, some can fly
>   Some are in cities, some are in ditties
>   Some wear trousers, some need browsers
>   Some are ground in the sea, some oversee the grounds

Where did my friend go?

Edit: Here's a small hint.

> These are 8 "types" of "residents" that share something in common, but the pair described in each line share an additional, or rather, a *more specific* aspect.

I'll add another, bigger hint tomorrow if this isn't enough.

Comment: Gah, I just had this genius idea that fits some of the clues but I'm having trouble making it fit a complete pair. >_<

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The city your friend visited is

> New York!

Some are high, some can fly

> New York Giants are tall and  the New York Jets can fly

Some are in cities, some are in ditties

> The New York Mets (metropolitans) and the New York Yankees (yankee doodle)

Some wear trousers, some need browsers

> Knicks (Knicerbookers) and Nets (internet browsers)

Some are ground in the sea, some oversee the grounds

> New York Islanders (island is a ground in the sea), New York Rangers

Comment: I think you meant the Rangers (they oversee the grounds).  But this has to be the answer!

Comment: Perfect! Well done!

Answer (score 2):

Another guess, hot off the press!

> Your friend went to Middle-Earth.

Some are high:

> Elves, as in High Elves.

Some can fly:

> Eagles.

Why those two go together:

> Both races prefer to remain aloof from the struggle, but will help in a moment of crisis.

Some are in cities:

> Men, the main city-dwellers of the Third Age.

Some are in ditties:

> Dwarves -- we don't see much of them outside the ditty about the ring.

Why those two go together:

> Both are warlike yet generally 'good guy' races.

Some wear trousers:

> Hobbits

Some need browsers:

> Rangers (they're always relying on their network of information, so an internet connection would really help out!)

Why those two go together:

> Both are not something the average Middle-Earth resident has likely heard of, because both like to keep private. Rangers aren't specifically a race, but I do think they're a special breed of men? (Some Elf-blood or something)

Some are ground in the sea:

> The Balrog I think. This was the hardest clue for me to fit because LotR doesn't really have many water-y scenes. Another guess: The ghosts living in the swamp outside of Mordor. But the Balrog is my main guess (it fell into that big lake under Moria in the movie, I thiiiink that's canonical in the book too).

Some oversee the grounds:

> Wizards -- their main task in life is just keeping a watch on things and keeping things running smoothly.

Why those two go together:

> Gandalf's duel with the Balrog, also, both are super-ancient super-powerful magical beings.

Comment: ROFL! I love this answer (even though I don't think it's right).

Answer (score 1):

Fasten your seat belts:

> Your friend went to Gjerde, which appears to be a small town in Norway! Why? Because it rhymes with:

Some are high:

> Byrd (the Byrds' music was sometimes banned for promoting recreational drugs)

Some can fly:

> Bird

Some are in cities:

> Kurd

Some are in ditties:

> Word

Some wear trousers:

> Nerd

Some need browsers:

> Third (according to a quick Google search, roughly 1/3 of all U.S. citizens don't have a home internet connection)

Some are ground in the sea:

> Gerd, a Norse Goddess 'commonly theorized to be a goddess associated with the earth' according to Wikipedia. Earth = ground!

Some oversee the grounds:

> Herd. Herds of grazing animals are great at keeping grass trimmed!

Comment: This was pretty clever! It's not the answer I'm looking for, and it doesn't fit with the hint, but I enjoyed it nonetheless!

Comment: This is crazy, off-the-wall, and awesome!

Answer (score -1):

I think it might be

> the land of creepy-crawlies.

*Some are high, some can fly*

> This could describe any flying insects.

*Some are in cities, some are in ditties*

> Ants and termites live in huge colonies that can be called cities.

*Some wear trousers, some need browsers*

> Browsers as in *web* browsers, as in *spider* webs.

*Some are ground in the sea, some oversee the grounds*

Not sure about this line (or about trousers and ditties above), but I think I might be onto something here...